# App crashing when assigning button-name through binding

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

I have buttons in a listbox and for each of them, I want
to provide a different name. This is how I setup the binding in XAML:

```
<Button Content="{Binding count}"
        x:Name="{Binding buttonName}"
        Width="55"
        Height="55"
        BorderThickness="3"
        FontSize="18.667"
        Padding="-1,-2,0,0"
        Margin="-400,0,0,0"
        FontWeight="Bold"
        Click="servingButtonClicked" />
```

`buttonName` is a string, which is stored in an object in a `LinkedList<string>` as an itemSource for this listBox.

Why won't this work?

Error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

x:Name must not bet via DataBinding - this is a name for the instance of the object, not something dynamic.

Comment: How could I achieve my goal otherwise?

Comment: Just set the unique name in XAML or not set it at all. I can't see a use for dataBinded button names.